# Android pattern lock implementation?

Tags: android, locking, design-patterns

I am developing an app and in this i need to implement pattern lock .How can i do this?
I have tried http://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/
 help please.

Comment: "implement pattern lock" is a useless description of what you are trying to do, and you have not indicated what specific problems you encountered with that library.

Answer (score 0):

try to extend GridView and handle onTouchEvents.